# Error al capturar String y hacerle casting a Int

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
public void agregarNumero()
{
    String numero;
    boolean agregado=false;

    numero = bokNumero.getText();
    int auxNumero=Integer.parseInt(numero);


    agregado = numeroHardy_Ramanujan.Recursivo_esHardyRamanujan(auxNumero, 1, 1);

    if (agregado)
    {
        Alert mensaje;
        mensaje = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        mensaje.setContentText("El numero es Hardy_Ramanujan");
        mensaje.showAndWait();
    }
    else
    {
        Alert mensaje = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        mensaje.setContentText("NO ES ");
        mensaje.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Al capturar el String y enviarlo al metodo que retorna un booleano, saltan errores me dice que el error esta en la linea donde realizo el cast a entero, Que podria ser? ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No habria por que originar error. ¿Que numero esta intentando capturar?, tener en cuenta que tan grande es, pues si no entra en el rango de los tipo de datos Integer, usar Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le puedes agregar un código de validación en caso que el valor de `numero` no sea válido:

```
public void agregarNumero()
{
    String numero;
    boolean agregado=false;

    numero = bokNumero.getText();

     if(!numero.chars().allMatch( c -> Character.isDigit(c)))
     {
            //notificar que el valor ingresado no es un número y regresar
            return;
     }

    int auxNumero=Integer.parseInt(numero);


    agregado = numeroHardy_Ramanujan.Recursivo_esHardyRamanujan(auxNumero, 1, 1);

    if (agregado)
    {
        Alert mensaje;
        mensaje = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        mensaje.setContentText("El numero es Hardy_Ramanujan");
        mensaje.showAndWait();
    }
    else
    {
        Alert mensaje = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        mensaje.setContentText("NO ES ");
        mensaje.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Estoy capturando el numero en un Textfield con el boton Ok le doy la accion para enviarlo al metodo, tendra algo que ver el boton?

Comment: `bokNumero ` es el nombre del textfield o del botón?

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de mi error, estaba enviando el boton y no el texto, Debo prestar mas atencion., Gracias carlos